# Browser shows stale JSP page, user has to refresh manually

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jstl

I'm working on a website in JSP. There is a page called Agency which is publicly visible and shows the details of an agency. However, when an "Agency Admin" is logged in, the same Agency page is rendered with Add/Edit links to modify the data on the page.

The problem is this:

- A user visits the Agency page (Not logged in at this point)
- This user logs in as an Agency Admin and navigates to the agency page again
- The agency page doesn't show the Add/Edit links until the user manually refreshes the browser

This is what the link to the Agency page looks like:

```
<a href="agency.do?agencyId=<core:out value="${agency.agencyId}" />">
    <core:out value="${agency.name}" />
</a>
```

I've been using this as a workaround:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:window.location = 'home.do?agencyId=<core:out value="${agency.agencyId}" />&rnd=' + Math.random()">
    <core:out value="${agency.name}" />
</a>
```

I'm appending a random number to the URL using javascript. But using `onclick` instead of `href` doesn't feel like the right thing to do. What if the user wants to open the link in a new tab?

I thought this would be a fairly common problem. Any better solution to this?

Comment: And the JSTL hurts my eyes. Suggestions to improve readability are also welcome.

Comment: It's more readable than *scriptlets*. I'd only suggest to set that `core` prefix back to `c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your browser or a proxy must cache the page. Try adding those headers to the response of the page which is cached and shouldn't be :

```
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
response.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

Regarding the JSTL usage, I would have two remarks:

1. The usual prefix for the core library is `c`, not `core`.
2. A URL is supposed to be composed using the `<c:url>` tag. This tag takes care of

   - taking absolute URLs (starting with `/`) and pre-pending the context root of the app (`/agency.do` becomes `/myApp/agency.do`)
   - adding the session ID to the URL if URL rewriting is necessary
   - encoding the URL parameters correctly

For example:

```
<c:url var="agencyUrl" value="agency.do">
    <c:param name="agencyId" value="${agency.agencyId}" />
</c:url>
<a href="${fn:escapeXml(agencyUrl)}"><c:out value="${agency.name}" /></a>
```